# Bind nested XML to DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, linq, nested, linq-to-xml

I get a XML over a HttpWebRequest, then I search for the values I need, list them and show over a DataGridView.

After a lot of searching I found that my XML cannot be easily bound to a DataGridView because its nested and i need to format this data before.

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<feed xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:tel="http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/">
  <id>https://tel.search.ch/api/MEINPRIVATERAPIKEY/68e7af8f8efa353de6d0b05f798598f4</id>
  <title type="text">tel.search.ch API Search Results</title>
  <generator version="1.0" uri="https://tel.search.ch">tel.search.ch</generator>
  <updated>2007-03-22T03:00:00Z</updated>
  <link href="https://tel.search.ch/result.html?name=john+meier&amp;maxnum=2" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />
  <link href="https://tel.search.ch/api/?was=john+meier&amp;maxnum=2&amp;key=MEINPRIVATERAPIKEY" type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" />
  <link href="https://tel.search.ch/api/?was=john+meier&amp;maxnum=2&amp;pos=3&amp;key=MEINPRIVATERAPIKEY" rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" />
  <openSearch:totalResults>14</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>2</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <openSearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="john meier" startPage="1" />
  <entry>
    <id>urn:uuid:b4f420fda52419f2</id>
    <updated>2007-03-22T03:00:00Z</updated>
    <published>2007-03-22T03:00:00Z</published>
    <title type="text">Meier, John</title>
    <content type="text">Meier, John
    Marienfeldstrasse 92
    8252 Schlatt/TG
    *052 654 42 30</content>
    <autor>
      <name>tel.search.ch</name>
    </autor>
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/detail/b4f420fda52419f2" title="Details" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/vcard/Meier.vcf?key=b4f420fda52419f2" type="text/x-vcard" title="VCard Download" rel="alternate" />
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/edit/?id=b4f420fda52419f2" rel="edit" type="text/html" />
    <tel:pos>1</tel:pos>
    <tel:id>b4f420fda52419f2</tel:id>
    <tel:type>Person</tel:type>
    <tel:name>Meier</tel:name>
    <tel:firstname>John</tel:firstname>
    <tel:occupation></tel:occupation>
    <tel:street>Marienfeldstrasse</tel:street>
    <tel:streetno>92</tel:streetno>
    <tel:zip>8252</tel:zip>
    <tel:city>Schlatt</tel:city>
    <tel:canton>TG</tel:canton>
    <tel:phone>+41526544230</tel:phone>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>urn:uuid:c8c043412a3ce526</id>
    <updated>2007-03-22T03:00:00Z</updated>
    <published>2007-03-22T03:00:00Z</published>
    <title type="text">John Meier IT-Consulting</title>
    <content type="text">John Meier IT-Consulting
    Unterdorfstrasse 22
    4143 Dornach/SO
    061 723 62 92</content>
    <autor>
      <name>tel.search.ch</name>
    </autor>
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/detail/c8c043412a3ce526" title="Details" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/vcard/Meier.vcf?key=c8c043412a3ce526" type="text/x-vcard" title="VCard Download" rel="alternate" />
    <link href="https://tel.search.ch/edit/?id=c8c043412a3ce526" rel="edit" type="text/html" />
    <tel:pos>2</tel:pos>
    <tel:id>c8c043402a3ce526</tel:id>
    <tel:type>Organisation</tel:type>
    <tel:name>John Meier IT Consulting</tel:name>
    <tel:occupation>Your Personal IT-Consultant</tel:occupation>
    <tel:street>Unterdorfstrasse</tel:street>
    <tel:streetno>22</tel:streetno>
    <tel:zip>4143</tel:zip>
    <tel:city>Dornach</tel:city>
    <tel:canton>SO</tel:canton>
    <tel:category>Software Grosshandel</tel:category>
    <tel:category>Software &amp; Consulting</tel:category>
    <tel:phone>+41617236292</tel:phone>
    <tel:extra type="fax">+41617236393</tel:extra>
    <tel:extra type="mobile">+41763341010</tel:extra>
    <tel:extra type="email">john.meier@mymail.com</tel:extra>
    <tel:extra type="website">http://www.johnmeierconsult.com</tel:extra>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

My code:

```
// Get XML from API
var url = "https://tel.search.ch/examples/api-response.xml";
var doc = new XDocument();

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
}

// Format Data
var query = from el in doc.Descendants("entry")
select new
{
    Position = el.Element("pos").Value,
    Id = el.Element("id").Value,
    Type = el.Element("type").Value,
    Name = el.Element("name").Value,
    Firstname = el.Element("firstname").Value,
    Occupation = el.Element("occupation").Value,
    Street = el.Element("street").Value,
    StreetNo = el.Element("streetno").Value,
    Zip = el.Element("zip").Value,
    City = el.Element("city").Value,
    Canton = el.Element("canton").Value,
    Phone = el.Element("phone").Value
};

// Bind Query to DataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

I try to show a row with every possible value for each entry in the XML.

While debugging this way:

```
var result = from xml in doc.Descendants() 
                select xml;

foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Element {0} = {1}",
        element.Name, element.Value);
}
```

I can see the following Data:

```
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed = https://tel.search.ch/api/MEINPRIVATERAPIKEY/68e7af8f8efa353de6d0b05f798598f4tel.search.ch API Search Resultstel.search.ch2007-03-22T03:00:00Z1412urn:uuid:b4f420fda52419f22007-03-22T03:00:00Z2007-03-22T03:00:00ZMeier, JohnMeier, John
    Marienfeldstrasse 92
    8252 Schlatt/TG
    *052 654 42 30tel.search.ch1b4f420fda52419f2PersonMeierJohnMarienfeldstrasse928252SchlattTG+41526544230urn:uuid:c8c043412a3ce5262007-03-22T03:00:00Z2007-03-22T03:00:00ZJohn Meier IT-ConsultingJohn Meier IT-Consulting
    Unterdorfstrasse 22
    4143 Dornach/SO
    061 723 62 92tel.search.ch2c8c043402a3ce526OrganisationJohn Meier IT ConsultingYour Personal IT-ConsultantUnterdorfstrasse224143DornachSOSoftware GrosshandelSoftware & Consulting+41617236292+41617236393+41763341010john.meier@mymail.comhttp://www.johnmeierconsult.com
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id = https://tel.search.ch/api/MEINPRIVATERAPIKEY/68e7af8f8efa353de6d0b05f798598f4
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title = tel.search.ch API Search Results
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}generator = tel.search.ch
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated = 2007-03-22T03:00:00Z
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/}totalResults = 14
Element {http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/}startIndex = 1
Element {http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/}itemsPerPage = 2
Element {http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/}Query = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry = urn:uuid:b4f420fda52419f22007-03-22T03:00:00Z2007-03-22T03:00:00ZMeier, JohnMeier, John
    Marienfeldstrasse 92
    8252 Schlatt/TG
    *052 654 42 30tel.search.ch1b4f420fda52419f2PersonMeierJohnMarienfeldstrasse928252SchlattTG+41526544230
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id = urn:uuid:b4f420fda52419f2
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated = 2007-03-22T03:00:00Z
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published = 2007-03-22T03:00:00Z
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title = Meier, John
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content = Meier, John
    Marienfeldstrasse 92
    8252 Schlatt/TG
    *052 654 42 30
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}autor = tel.search.ch
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}name = tel.search.ch
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}pos = 1
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}id = b4f420fda52419f2
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}type = Person
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}name = Meier
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}firstname = John
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}occupation = 
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}street = Marienfeldstrasse
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}streetno = 92
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}zip = 8252
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}city = Schlatt
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}canton = TG
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}phone = +41526544230
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry = urn:uuid:c8c043412a3ce5262007-03-22T03:00:00Z2007-03-22T03:00:00ZJohn Meier IT-ConsultingJohn Meier IT-Consulting
    Unterdorfstrasse 22
    4143 Dornach/SO
    061 723 62 92tel.search.ch2c8c043402a3ce526OrganisationJohn Meier IT ConsultingYour Personal IT-ConsultantUnterdorfstrasse224143DornachSOSoftware GrosshandelSoftware & Consulting+41617236292+41617236393+41763341010john.meier@mymail.comhttp://www.johnmeierconsult.com
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id = urn:uuid:c8c043412a3ce526
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}updated = 2007-03-22T03:00:00Z
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}published = 2007-03-22T03:00:00Z
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title = John Meier IT-Consulting
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content = John Meier IT-Consulting
    Unterdorfstrasse 22
    4143 Dornach/SO
    061 723 62 92
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}autor = tel.search.ch
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}name = tel.search.ch
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link = 
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}pos = 2
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}id = c8c043402a3ce526
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}type = Organisation
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}name = John Meier IT Consulting
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}occupation = Your Personal IT-Consultant
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}street = Unterdorfstrasse
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}streetno = 22
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}zip = 4143
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}city = Dornach
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}canton = SO
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}category = Software Grosshandel
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}category = Software & Consulting
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}phone = +41617236292
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}extra = +41617236393
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}extra = +41763341010
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}extra = john.meier@mymail.com
Element {http://tel.search.ch/api/spec/result/1.0/}extra = http://www.johnmeierconsult.com
```

I am really lost and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting back null.  I modified code to handle namespaces a remove "Value" which gives exceptions when item is null.  Instead cast to string

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication94
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "https://tel.search.ch/examples/api-response.xml";
            var doc = new XDocument();

            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
            }
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace telNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("tel");

            // Format Data
            var query = from el in doc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                        select new
                        {
                            Position = (string)el.Element(telNs + "pos"),
                            Id = (string)el.Element(telNs + "id"),
                            Type = (string)el.Element(telNs + "type"),
                            Name = (string)el.Element(telNs + "name"),
                            Firstname = (string)el.Element(telNs + "firstname"),
                            Occupation = (string)el.Element(telNs + "occupation"),
                            Street = (string)el.Element(telNs + "street"),
                            StreetNo = (string)el.Element(telNs + "streetno"),
                            Zip = (string)el.Element(telNs + "zip"),
                            City = (string)el.Element(telNs + "city"),
                            Canton = (string)el.Element(telNs + "canton"),
                            Phone = (string)el.Element(telNs + "phone")
                            email = el.Elements(telNs + "extra").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "email").Select(x => (string)x).ToList() //use FirstOrDefault() if you only want one.
                        };
            var list = query.ToList();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Hi jdweng, thats a very nice and clean solution thanks!

Do you know how can I reach something like this? "/feed/entry/tel:extra/@type='email'"